# What happened to comment formatting?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

I just [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356756/rounded-corners-on-divs-without-using-images/2356820#2356820) an answer on Stack Overflow. To indicate markup, I surrounded a `<b>` tag with backticks. But opposite to my expectations, the comment didn't get properly formatted, the backticks just appeared as backticks, like `<b>`.

As you can see in the comments below, putting an ‘s’ at the end triggers this bug, like `<b>`s; strangely enough, I wrote these kind of tags before, like `<span>`s, but never got this problem.

Comment: Just a test: *italics*, **bold**, `code`.

Comment: Another test: `<b>` (backticks around angle brackets around b, as described in the post).

Comment: And now exactly the same, with an ‘s’ at the end: `<b>`s and some other text.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51417/bug-using-the-markdown-in-comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design -- comments use a stricter, minimal markdown, and only allow certain characters (space, and some punctuation) to terminate code blocks.

**Edit:** Backtick handling in comments is now [closer to real Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981), so this works now.