# Backticks in comments don't work when you're adding a plural to the end

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown, code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to comment formatting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51091/what-happened-to-comment-formatting)

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168160/begin-rescue-not-catching-error/3168200#3168200),

```
`Exception`s
```

doesn't get turned into `Exception`s, but remains as

```
`Exception`s
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51417/bug-using-the-markdown-in-comments and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51091/what-happened-to-comment-formatting cover this.

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: @dmckee Eh? The second one even speaks directly about adding an "s" after comment formatting. That's about as plural as you can get in the majority of words, and they're both about getting `problem`s in your comments.

Comment: @Grace: That was *"No, backticks don't work right in comments."* Sorry for the confusion. I merely meant to imply that comments, being lightweight are not fully functional.

Comment: @dmckee Ah, sorry about that, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design -- comments use a stricter, minimal markdown, and only allow certain characters (space, and some punctuation) to terminate code blocks.

**Edit:** Okay, [this works now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981).

Comment: Is this a documented or undocumented feature?

Comment: @Andrew: now that Jeff has mentioned it, it can be considered documented. (^_^)