# Comment Inline Code Markdown Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

Using inline code Markdown (backticks ``) in comments and following it immediately with a non-whitespace character breaks the Markdown causing the backticks to appear and not having the stuff inside the backticks interpreted as code. Strangely this behavior does not appear within posts and answers:

- With letters: `test`s
- With punctuations: `test`!

It's becoming slightly annoying because a) the behavior is inconsistent and b) I refer to HTML elements as plurals like `<br>`s and `<li>`s, and now I have to insert an entirely useless space between them that when read makes it look weird.

**Edit** As the faq suggest, I should update my post with information on how I attempted to solve the problem myself if nobody takes notice. So, here I am bumping up this post. Oh, and freehand circles:

[image]

As you can see, the new version of Paint included in Windows 7 takes it to a whole new level.

Comment: `test`s. See! Its annoying.

Comment: This has been brought up already, but I think the other question should be closed as a duplicate of this, because this is asked better. - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51417/bug-using-the-markdown-in-comments

Comment: These tend to get closed as "[by-design] comment markdown is more limited", for reasons passing understanding

Comment: Here's [one such bydesign ruling](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51091/what-happened-to-comment-formatting "It's also asking about the same instance of following an HTML tag with an S").

Comment: My search only brought out the one @jjnguy noted, and that one was just as ignored, old and stale as this one probably will be.

Comment: @Michael, it should retagged to [by-sloth] :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't very well say "no" to freehand circles.

[This works now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981).